# How to build a graph page like this one?

Tags: javascript, css

I came accoss this webpage: http://www.concerthotels.com/100-years-of-rock and it is very cool. I would like to build some content with similar looking.

Is it possible that someone could give me a direction how this page is built? Thanks a lot for that.

Comment: Javascript, css and html my friend

Comment: Pretty, but looks like a spoiler

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! First of all, we can't make projects for you, that's your job. We can help you as soon as you're stuck though, but then you have to show us the efforts you've made already. A good first place to start is to use de developer tools of your browser (usually F12) and check the code of the site. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is made with javascript , css , html5

- there are many jquery plugin like scroll magic who can give you the same effect as scrolling content automatically or made you own timeline : (http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/)
- also drawing and animating lines can made with SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics ), visit for more information (http://www.w3schools.com/svg/) .

hope this can give you a small view of how you can do the same effect :)